# How to set character encoding to ServletContext logs in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, logging

From my servlet I call the method:

```
getServletContext().log("Può chiedermi il saldo");
```

But in Tomcat 8.5 log file (/tomcat/logs/localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log) I obtain the text with wrong encoding:

```
 Pu? chiedermi il saldo
```

Anyone knows how to set logs charset to ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 2):

See [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Servlets_logging_API).

The encoding used by `org.apache.juli.FileHandler` or `AsyncFileHandler` (that writes the file) is configured by its `.encoding` property. The configuration properties are listed in [Javadoc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) for the class.

I usually explicitly configure it to use UTF-8

```
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Just a note for beginners like me... add the property to the logging.properties file placed in $CATALINA_BASE/conf